# Hibernate query (comparing sums) - grails, across two different datasources

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have this code and just works fine. i just want to ask if this is also possible if I use *executeQuery* like comparing sum in a subquery, I think querying using *executeQuery* will process faster than my existing code. here is my code:

```
    def availableSched = []
    def tres = TestRoomExamSchedule.getAll()
    tres.each { t ->
        def stres = StudentTestRoomExamSchedule.countByTestRoomExamSchedule(t)
        if (stres < t.testRoom.totalTestStations && t.examSchedule.actualExamDateTime <= new Date()) {
           availableSched.add(t) 
        }
    }        
    return availableSched
```

This one returns a List of *TestRoomExamSchedule* which satisfies the following Criteria:
*1)TestRoom.totalTestStations is > student which is in the StudentTestRoomExamSchedule.
2)ExamSchedule.actualExamDateTime is <= now.*

I have these Domain Classes:

```
class TestRoom {

String code
String name
int totalTestStations

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    datasource 'admin'
    table 'testroom'
    code column: 'code'
    name column: 'name'
    totalTestStations column: 'totaltestmach', sqlType: "smallint"
}
```

TestRoomExamSchedule Domain class

```
class TestRoomExamSchedule implements Serializable{

Long testRoomId
ExamSchedule examSchedule
TestRoom testRoom   

static transients = ['testRoom']

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    table 'testroom_examschedule'
    version false
    id generator: 'assigned', composite: ['testingCenterId','examSchedule']
    testRoomId column: 'testingcenter_id'
    examSchedule column: 'examschedule_id'

}
```

StudentTestRoomExamSchedule Domain class

```
class StudentTestRoomExamSchedule implements Serializable {

Student student
TestRoomExamSchedule testRoomExamSchedule

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    table 'person_examschedule'
    version: false
    id composite: ['student', 'testRoomExamSchedule']
    student column: 'person_id'
    columns {
        testingCenterExamSchedule {
         column name: 'testroom_id'
         column name: 'examschedule_id'
        }
    }
}
```

I am using two different datasources that's why i need to declare the property *testRoom* in transient in my domain class *TestRoomExamSchedule*.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two different data sources, it's probably impossible.

I can only imagine a couple of very narrow cases where inter-database operations are possible in a single query.